# what is going on in this code, is it adding all the invalid characters in the char array?

Tags: c#

Is the above statement adding all the invalid path characters in the array? When I run the `foreach` loop to print all the invalid path characters, I get nothing on the console.

This is my foreach loop:

Comment: If you are unsure, debug it.

Comment: Most invalid characters are non-printable, but I can't see why you aren't getting `"`, `<`, `>` and `|`.

Comment: It works for me. Set a breakpoint at your `foreach` statement and view the contents of `PathCharsList` in the debugger.

Comment: When I run the debugger I get "\0" as the Invalid path character and "\0" and "/" as the Invalid Filename character. I guess they are non-printable.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. As stated in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names. The full set of invalid characters can vary by file system.

Thus, irrespective of whether or not the return value of `GetInvalidPathChars` arrives correctly in the console, it will never be guaranteed to include all invalid path characters.